# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python

Tags: python, mysql

iam getting error while installing modules in python using pip3.7, [error screenshot(executing from /usr/src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM3jS.png)

python installed location '/usr/src/Python3.7.11',
i tried both '**pip3.7 install mysql-connector-python**' and '**pip3.7 install mysql-connector-python-rf**'
also tried following procedure

1.**sudo yum install openssl-devel**
cd to python3.7.11
**sudo ./configure**
**sudo make**
**sudo make install**

2.**yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel
readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel libpcap-devel xz-devel**
cd to python3.7.11
**make**
**make install**

above methods did not work for me .please help to overcome this, thanks in advance
[error screenshot(executing from root location)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUOrQ.png)

Comment: Do you have two python versions installed?

Comment: yes i have installed two versions, python2.6 came with os (default one), python3.7 installed at location /usr/src/python3.7.11 ,which python( /usr/bin/python),which python3.7(/usr/local/bin/python3.7)